# Cannot create property 'type' on string 'xpath' in Cypress error

Tags: xpath, cypress, cypress-xpath

Installed "cypress-xpath" plugin into Cypress (according to the instructions), inserted "require('cypress-xpath')" into my e2e.js file, used cy.xpath(...) and run the test.

While in test execution, it popped Error message, below:

```
Cannot create property 'type' on string 'xpath'
```

EDIT: This is my e2e.js

```
// This example support/e2e.js is processed and
// loaded automatically before your test files.
//
// This is a great place to put global configuration and
// behavior that modifies Cypress.
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off
// automatically serving support files with the
// 'supportFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/configuration
// ***********************************************************

// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands'


// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')
require('cypress-xpath')
```

The error is thrown just after "require('cypress-xpath')" in this file.
Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: @barh your files seems good to me as have copied the same to my e2e.js and Test cases are working good. May be push your code repo to github and share the link. Please remove anything that's your company and project specific. Thanks